# Select only rows which the SUM of specific column is distinct to zero with group by another colum SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum, sql-server-2017

I want to filter a table eliminating the rows that give zero in a sum over an "amount" column and that are grouped by an Id, for example, if I have "-10, 10 and 15" for the same Id. I want to eliminate the rows that have -10 and 10 and stay with row 15

So far I was able to filter the table using `GROUP BY` but I need to get the ID to do a select again on the same table, also I need the `SUM` split.

```sql
CREATE Table #myData 
(
    Id INT, 
    DateInit date, 
    DebtorName varchar(10), 
    Trancode varchar(10), 
    Amount VARCHAR(50), 
    DebtorID varchar(50), 
    ClientRef NVARCHAR(256)
)

INSERT INTO #myData 
VALUES
 (1, '1/1/2022', 'BURNETTE', '13 P', '-53.42', '23916762', 'T081819513107-00009') 
,(2, '1/1/2022', 'BURNETTE', '13 P', '-28.83', '23916761', 'T081819513107-00008') 
,(3, '1/1/2022', 'BURNETTE', '13 P', '-12.08', '23916764', 'T081819513107-00010') 
,(4, '1/1/2022', 'BURNETTE', '1 P', '12.08', '23916764', 'T081819513107-00010') 
,(5, '1/1/2022', 'BURNETTE', '1 P', '28.83', '23916761', 'T081819513107-00008') 
,(6, '1/1/2022', 'BURNETTE', '1 P', '53.42', '23916762', 'T081819513107-00009') 
,(7, '1/1/2022', 'BURNETTE', '2 P', '66.41', '23916762', 'T081819513107-00009') 
,(8, '1/1/2022', 'BURNETTE', '2 P', '71.10', '23916762', 'T081819513107-00009') 
,(9, '1/1/2022', 'BURNETTE', '2 P', '12.08', '23916764', 'T081819513107-00010') 

SELECT 
    DebtorID, 
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN TRY_PARSE(A.Amount AS float) IS NULL
                THEN (-1) * CAST(SUBSTRING(A.Amount, CHARINDEX('-', A.amount) + 1, LEN(A.Amount)) AS float)
                ELSE CAST(A.Amount AS float)
        END) AS amountSum
FROM 
    #myData A
GROUP BY 
    DebtorID
HAVING 
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN TRY_PARSE(A.Amount AS float) IS NULL
                THEN (-1) * CAST(SUBSTRING(A.Amount, CHARINDEX('-', A.Amount) + 1, LEN(A.Amount)) AS float)
                ELSE CAST(A.Amount AS float)
        END) != 0
```

But this query returns:

| DebtorID | amountSum |
| --- | --- |
| 23916762 | 137.51 |
| 23916764 | 12.08 |

The ultimate goal is to filter these results and save them in another table identical to the original (`#myData`).

This is what I want to achieve for input #myData :

| Id | DateInit | DebtorName | Trancode | amount | DebtorID | ClientRef |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 1/1/2022 | BURNETTE | 2 P | 66.41 | 23916762 | T081819513107-00009 |
| 8 | 1/1/2022 | BURNETTE | 2 p | 71.10 | 23916762 | T081819513107-00009 |
| 8 | 1/1/2022 | BURNETTE | 2 p | 12.08 | 23916764 | T081819513107-00010 |

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

### Update 2 - new scenario

thanks for the help, but this scenario has to have the same output.

| Id | DateInit | DebtorName | Trancode | amount | DebtorID | ClientRef |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 | BURNETTE | 13 P | -53.42 | 23916762 | T081819513107-00009 |
| 2 | 1/1/2022 | BURNETTE | 13 P | -12.08 | 23916764 | T081819513107-00010 |
| 3 | 1/1/2022 | BURNETTE | 1 p | 12.08 | 23916764 | T081819513107-00010 |
| 4 | 1/1/2022 | BURNETTE | 1 p | 28.83 | 23916761 | T081819513107-00008 |
| 5 | 1/1/2022 | BURNETTE | 1 p | 66.41 | 23916762 | T081819513107-00009 |
| 6 | 1/1/2022 | BURNETTE | 13 p | -28.83 | 23916761 | T081819513107-00008 |
| 7 | 1/1/2022 | BURNETTE | 1 p | 53.42 | 23916762 | T081819513107-00009 |
| 8 | 1/1/2022 | BURNETTE | 1 p | 71.10 | 23916762 | T081819513107-00009 |
| 9 | 1/1/2022 | BURNETTE | 2 p | 12.08 | 23916764 | T081819513107-00010 |

the expected result output:

| Id | DateInit | DebtorName | Trancode | amount | DebtorID | ClientRef |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1/1/2022 | BURNETTE | 1 p | 66.41 | 23916762 | T081819513107-00009 |
| 8 | 1/1/2022 | BURNETTE | 1 p | 71.10 | 23916762 | T081819513107-00009 |
| 9 | 1/1/2022 | BURNETTE | 2 p | 12.08 | 23916764 | T081819513107-00010 |

Comment: Please manually construct a table of your expected results for this input data. It sounds like you need a window query but it's not 100% clear.

Comment: ***WHY*** do you make your `Amount` column a `VARCHAR` ?!??!? It's **quite clearly** a numerical value - so define it as a numerical value and you can save yourself all those messy `CAST` and conversions and everything! Also: I'd recommend making it a `DECIMAL(p,s)` datatype, since `FLOAT` is notoriously fraught with rounding and precision issues.....

Comment: Are you only looking for removing exact mirror amounts ie:
-50 and +50. Or should stuff like: -50, +30, -50, +100 also lead to just +30 being left? And what about:
-50, -50, 120, -20? Should everything be removed?

This can be all quite more complicated.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I already update the expected result.

Comment: @marc_s I know it's a mess but I can't change the type of the column

Comment: what happens when you get `-50` + `50`, `-50`, which of the `-50` gets removed, or does it not matter at all? If there isn't a common unique identifier to link the reciprocal transactions, then we need to do this in multiple passes over the data. Also, is there not a column (other than `Id`) that we can use to determine the order of the transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the original data set but want to include an aggregate or want to filter or sort based on an aggregate then *Window Functions* can help you out a lot.

> **UPDATE:** The nature of the question has changed slightly, however the original advice is still the same, we don't want to use `GROUP BY` because we lose the detail rows, if we must do this in a sing expression then *Window Functions* provide a simple syntax solution

In this solution I've used a CTE to separate out the formatting of the amount column and the calculation of the aggregate, but you could have used `CROSS APPLY` for the formatting.

> Notice in the solution we are **NOT** applying a `SUM` at all, we are merely matching values, this means the same solution with work for non--numeric values

In the fiddle I've tried to detail some of the steps but ultimately, we process the data in the following sequence:

1. Format the `Amount` column into a numeric value

- This is actually a redundant but simplifies other aggregate operations you might make later

2. Identify the unique pairs of `Amount` and `DebtorID` values using [`ROW_NUMBER()` window function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)
3. Filter out the unique pairs that match
4. Return the processed data joined back with any additional columns or references you might need.

```
WITH FormattedData as (
  SELECT ID, DebtorID, COALESCE(TRY_PARSE(amount as float)
                       , (-1)*CAST(SUBSTRING(amount,CHARINDEX('-',amount)+1,LEN(amount)) AS float)
                   ) as Amount
  FROM #myData
)
, DataSequenced as (
 SELECT a.ID, a.DebtorID, a.Amount, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.DebtorID, a.Amount ORDER BY a.ID) as RN
 FROM FormattedData a
)
, MatchesRemoved as (
  SELECT a.ID, a.DebtorID, A.Amount
  FROM DataSequenced a
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT lkp.ID 
                    FROM DataSequenced lkp 
                    WHERE lkp.DebtorID = a.DebtorID
                      AND lkp.Amount = -a.Amount
                      AND lkp.RN = a.RN)
)

SELECT myData.ID, DateInit, DebtorName, Trancode, a.Amount, myData.DebtorID
  , myData.ClientRef
 FROM MatchesRemoved a
 INNER JOIN #myData myData ON myData.ID = a.ID
ORDER BY ID
```

See it in this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/XY8h2uvG

Because we are not specifically applying an aggregate on the `Amount` column, it doesn't *need* to be numeric, we can actually use simple string comparisons. You will have to profile this in your environment, but the following query is similar:

```
WITH DataSequenced as (
 SELECT a.ID, a.DebtorID, a.Amount
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.DebtorID, a.Amount ORDER BY a.ID) as RN
  , CASE
        WHEN LEFT(a.Amount,1) = '-' THEN RTRIM(RIGHT(a.Amount, LEN(a.Amount) - 1)) 
        ELSE RTRIM(a.Amount)
    END as AbsAmount
 FROM #myData a
)
, MatchesRemoved as (
  SELECT a.ID, a.DebtorID, A.Amount
  FROM DataSequenced a
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT lkp.ID 
                    FROM DataSequenced lkp 
                    WHERE lkp.DebtorID = a.DebtorID
                      AND lkp.AbsAmount = a.AbsAmount
                      AND lkp.ID <> a.ID
                      AND lkp.RN = a.RN)
)
SELECT myData.ID, DateInit, DebtorName, Trancode, a.Amount, myData.DebtorID
  , myData.ClientRef
 FROM MatchesRemoved a
 INNER JOIN #myData myData ON myData.ID = a.ID
ORDER BY ID
```

Depending on the complexity of your datasource and the indexes that might be available (or **NOT** available) It might make more sense to process this in multiple queries against temporary tables.

---

> The following are previous attempts to address the original request. I choose to leave these in due to the ambiguity of the OP title, the though process and solutions (including the fiddles) might prove helpful to others who find themselves on this page.

*Find the transactions where the SUM of the Debtor is ZERO* : This was interpreted as **return all transactions for Debtors who do not have a ZERO balance.**

https://dbfiddle.uk/l-64hpZF

```
WITH FormattedData as (
  SELECT ID, DebtorID, COALESCE(TRY_PARSE(amount as float)
                       , (-1)*CAST(SUBSTRING(amount,CHARINDEX('-',amount)+1,LEN(amount)) AS float)
                   ) as Amount
  FROM #myData
)
, DataWithSum as (
 SELECT ID, DebtorID, Amount,  SUM(Amount) OVER( Partition By DebtorID) AS SumAmount
 FROM FormattedData
)
SELECT myData.ID, myData.DebtorID, D.Amount, D.SumAmount
  , myData.ClientRef
 FROM DataWithSum D
 -- join back if you need additional columns
 INNER JOIN #myData myData ON myData.ID = D.ID
 WHERE SumAmount > 0
```

| ID | DebtorID | Amount | SumAmount | ClientRef |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23916762 | -53.42 | 137.51 | T081819513107-00009 |
| 3 | 23916764 | -12.08 | 12.08 | T081819513107-00010 |
| 4 | 23916764 | 12.08 | 12.08 | T081819513107-00010 |
| 6 | 23916762 | 53.42 | 137.51 | T081819513107-00009 |
| 7 | 23916762 | 66.41 | 137.51 | T081819513107-00009 |
| 8 | 23916762 | 71.1 | 137.51 | T081819513107-00009 |
| 9 | 23916764 | 12.08 | 12.08 | T081819513107-00010 |

- I hope you can appreciate how much easier this sort of logic is if you store numeric values in a numeric typed column.

You could also have joined the result of your `GROUP BY` back onto the original set, if your `HAVING` clause was going to remove a ***LOT*** of records, then this can be more efficient than the *Window Function*

---

### Update: Running Balance - Only show the most recent transactions since a zero balance

If we need to balance out the transactions, then a simple solution is that we can compute the running balance for all previous rows with the same `DebtorID`. In this fiddle you can see the working out: https://dbfiddle.uk/DVRoMoNd

### Update #2: Filtering by >0 is not enough

I turns out that even though the previous fiddle returned the correct answer, it wouldn't work if the transaction history had previously gone into negatives and then back to zero. The following query finds the last time that the running balance was *less than or equal to* zero and returns all the transactions after that: https://dbfiddle.uk/exwm9OwA

```
-- if we only want the transactions since the last time the account was in balance
WITH FormattedData as (
  SELECT ID, DebtorID, COALESCE(TRY_PARSE(amount as float)
                       , (-1)*CAST(SUBSTRING(amount,CHARINDEX('-',amount)+1,LEN(amount)) AS float)
                   ) as Amount
  FROM #myData
)
, DataWithRunningBalance as (
 SELECT a.ID, a.DebtorID, a.Amount, (
                                     SELECT SUM(Amount) 
                                     FROM FormattedData lkp
                                     WHERE lkp.DebtorID = a.DebtorID
                                     AND lkp.ID <= a.ID
                                    ) AS SumAmount
 FROM FormattedData a
)
SELECT myData.ID, myData.DebtorID, A.Amount
  , myData.ClientRef
 FROM FormattedData A
 INNER JOIN #myData myData ON myData.ID = A.ID
 WHERE A.ID > (
               SELECT TOP 1 ID 
               FROM DataWithRunningBalance B 
               WHERE B.DebtorID = myData.DebtorID 
                 AND SumAmount <= 0 
               ORDER BY ID DESC
              )
ORDER BY ID
```

| ID | DebtorID | Amount | ClientRef |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 23916762 | 66.41 | T081819513107-00009 |
| 8 | 23916762 | 71.1 | T081819513107-00009 |
| 9 | 23916764 | 12.08 | T081819513107-00010 |

The *sequence* of the data is important to the `SumAmount` column, in this case I couldn't use the timestamp because there was not enough granularity in the values, `ID` was a natural fit *for **this** dataset*. In your production code there might be a a more suitable time based candidate.

The order of the *negative* vs *positive* values does not matter, `SumAmount` is a simple *running balance* with respect to *time of entry*.

Comment: I have a feeling he wants have some kind of accountancy thing of removing posts that together goes to 0, but leave all the other differences as they were. So, a whole sum of values won't do him good

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, that's just an old school running balance, i can do that, but not on my phone...

Comment: @ChrisSchaller yes, it's precisely what siggemannen says, I already update my question with the expected result. I've been struggling with this for a long time. I do not have much experience with Window Function.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller thanks a lot for your help, this works but I realized that negative values could come after positive values and the result is not always correct, I will continue from your code to try to fix that scenario

Comment: @brunovalverde the order is important, to determine everything `before`, but the order of the negatives vs the positives won't affect the result. What you are missing is a reliable timestamp sequence, in this query I can only use the ID to determine the correct sequence, but that might not work in you production environment.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller Yes, I just put a new scenario in my question, the problem comes from the fact that they are not in order, they are jobs that I cannot control and unfortunately I do not have a timestamp that I can use

Comment: Thanks @siggemannen I think I got there in the end ;)

Comment: @ChrisSchaller Thank you very much, the last update turned out as expected, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't know guys. if a guy has following sequence:
-50, 30, 50
the last update #2 returns just +50 which feels a bit weird to me. I think the way to attack this problem is multiple iterations over 1) matching transactions 2) test various combos (which i think could be an NP hard problem :D)